# SQLite LIKE - cannot (== doesn't know how to) convert not-English letters to the same case

Tags: sql, internationalization, android-sqlite, sql-like

*Sorry for my English*

Text columns in my database contain *English* and *not-English* letters.

So I cannot retrieve (using `LIKE`) rows whose `Title` column meets (case-insentive) some pattern:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TitleColumn LIKE '%pattern%';
```

or even:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE UPPER(TitleColumn) LIKE UPPER('%pattern%');
```

For example. If field `Title` contains `"ГазПром"`, and `pattern` is `"газ"` (`Г` and `г` are the same letter in different cases), then neither of the two `SELECT` statements above cannot recognize a match.

What can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you want to compare something case-insensitive, or you accent insensitive (i.e. á vs. a), you specify the collation using `COLLATE` keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE TitleColumn LIKE '%pattern%' COLLATE 'German_CI_AI_SC';
```

Unfortunately, given its documentation I don't think SQLite supports `COLLATE` in selection, and at the same time it does not seem to support language-specific collations.
Please keep in mind, that case-insensitive comparisons require you to specify the language, as it case conversion rules differ between various languages...